# TYPO3 Frontend User Repository

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I've got some problems upgrading my extension from TYPO3 6.2 to 7.6.X

got this code

```
/**
 * Protected Variable FrontendUserRepository wird mit NULL initialisiert.
 *
 * @var \Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $FrontendUserRepository = NULL;
```

and got this error:
[image]

Comment: did you upgrade the version in your ext_emconf.php
in 'typo3' => '6.2-7.6.99', ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to spell the namespace correctly. In this case `TYPO3` has to be in upper case:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
```

The class should be loaded. No further actions required but flushing the system cache.

Btw: "TYPO3" is always the correct spelling :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Have found this just some miniutes ago too ... damn in 6.2.9 Typo3 is absolute proper. Thanks

Comment: "No further actions required" might be a bit misleading. I just (again) made the experience that the Controller would not inject a class where I switched from nothing to "@inject" - until I cleared the system cache. Deleting typo3temp/Cache wasn't enough.

Comment: You are correct, if you add an injection to a controller you have to rebuild the system cache! I'll update the answer :)